# d3 log scale does not display

Tags: d3.js, scale, logarithm

I want to display a contour plot with a logarithmic scale on both axes. I found this nice example to perform this task:

http://plnkr.co/edit/f1VThUpkHxUzxOBXmTCr?p=preview

However when I change the scale to logarithmic scale

```
var x = d3.scale.log()
    .range([0, width]);
```

instead of

```
var x = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([0, width]);
```

The axis simply disappear. I thought that the problem was that log(0) = -infinity however it does not change anything if I start at 1.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to change the **domain** to not start from 0 (I presume you changed the range)

```
x.domain([1, dx]);
```

---

Plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/RTzBztpVpR2GYXiVUogb?p=preview

---

[image]

Comment: saved me! log(0) was the problem!